# Which tapes and adhesives are vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan

I was reading a [forum thread](https://forums.redflagdeals.com/vegan-packaging-tape-2290571/) wherein it is claimed that some adhesives (packaging tape etc.) is not considered vegan. However, as is typical for such forums, the claims were not backed up with clear proof/evidence and were interspersed with irrelevant discussion. I assume Stack Exchange can do better.

**Which adhesives (as used in sticky tapes) are not vegan, in either of the following senses?**

- Contain actual animal products within them.
- Have been tested on animals at some stage.